# Will Salesforce ever drop support for Classic

Tags: lightning, release, support, salesforce-classic

Recently Salesforce have introduced Lightning Winter 17, will Salesforce at some point drop support for Classic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Lightning Experience FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ) (last updated October 2016) includes:

> Q: Can I still use Salesforce Classic?
> A: You have the choice of when
>   you want to move to the new Lightning Experience UI and which users
>   you want to migrate. You can continue to use Salesforce Classic as
>   long as you like, and we will continue to support the Classic UI.

Answer (score 7):

Salesforce has no plans to drop support for classic. It will be around for a long time to come. You'll notice that PDFs are still rendered in classic, that lightning components can be used in classic and that visual force pages can be used in a lightning container in lightning pages. There are far too many orgs that have a lot of money invested in custom visualforce pages for Salesforce to consider forcing them to lightning.

Answer (score 6):

Salesforce.com has not announced any plans to remove Classic at this time. I would expect that salesforce.com is trying to get rid of Classic as soon as possible, but they will not be able to do so until they can convince 100% (or very close) of their major clients to move to LEX entirely. This means that they need to have 100% feature parity with Classic, *and* offer enough features that are LEX-only to entice large clients to move to Lightning despite the costs of doing so. Based on what I know about how larger clients operate, I would expect that the absolutely earliest this might happen is 2020, with a more realistic outlook between 2023 and 2025.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity I called up Salesforce, after many re-directions, a manager told me that in his mind, SF will not "think about" stopping support for Classic anytime in the next 10 years.